Placeholder for IOS Widget is displayed on Home Screen
FIXED: It was actually about me setting the parent for my childContext. It was in some way manipulating the parent context and saving placeholder data to the parent. By deleting that line this issue was fixed.
I have been using my SwiftUI app for a while and noticed that my widget started showing the placeholder instead of the actual widget in random times. For the placeholder widget I used template data and it isn't meant to be displayed on the home screen. The comments left by the WidgetKit extension template stated that I shouldn't do fetch requests in the placeholders, so I didn't.
To create example items for placeholders or previews I created this function:
private func createExampleItem(_ count: Int = 1) -> [Birth] {
    let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    childContext.parent = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
    
    let exampleItem = Birth(context: childContext)
    exampleItem.name = "John Doe"
    exampleItem.date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 10, to: Date())
        
    do {
        try childContext.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
        
    var arr: [Birth] = []
        
    for _ in 1...count {
        arr.append(exampleItem)
    }
        
    return arr
}

In this function I used childContexts so that my example data wasn't saved to the actual viewContext.
Both my getSnapshot and placeholder functions use the createExampleItem function so I actually don't know if the widget displayed on the Home Screen is the snapshot or placeholder. I also can't test to see which one it is since it displays the placeholder in random times. If this isn't a known issue I will test and see if it's the snapshot or placeholder being displayed no matter how long it takes.
I also tried refreshing the widgets through a button I put in the app but it doesn't change anything.
Timeline Provider
struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent(), items: createExampleItem(), itemCount: 1)
    }

    func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Entry) -> Void) {
        let date = Date()
        var entry: SimpleEntry
        
        entry = SimpleEntry(date: date, configuration: configuration, items: createExampleItem(), itemCount: 1)
        
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<SimpleEntry>) -> ()) {
        networkManager.fetchDataAndFilter { items in
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: configuration, items: items, itemCount: items.count)
            
            
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .atEnd)
            
            completion(timeline)
        }
    }
}

Network Manager
class NetworkManager {
    private func fetchData() throws -> [Birth] {
        let context = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
        
        let request = Birth.fetchRequest()
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        
        return result
    }
    
    func fetchDataAndFilter(completion: @escaping ([Birth]) -> Void) {
        do {
            let items = try self.fetchData()
            
            let sorted = sortBirthItems(items: items, filter: true)
            
            completion(sorted)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

